# Can an equation of the form $\sin(\omega t) + at^2+bt=N$, with $a\neq 0$, be solved analytically?

Tags: trigonometry

> Can the equation of the form 
>   $$\sin(\omega t) + at^2+bt=N$$ 
>   where $a,b,N \in \mathbb{R}$ be solved analytically for $a \ne 0$?

It, for example, arises when the rotating object falls down subject to gravity. Solving such equation can allow to compute the time of the object touchdown.

Comment: Not that I know of. Are you sure you got your equation right? The $\sin \omega t$ term implies an oscillation due to elastic force, not rotation.

Comment: $ \sin \omega t$ is a harmonic oscillation due to the object rotation. It will be moving according to the quadratic law, but will also be spinning.

Comment: I am just curious how you got that equation.

Comment: Imagine a rotating object in a freefall. Its Z coordinate is decreasing as $-\frac{1}{2} g t^2$ and its rotation would add $\sin \omega t$ for each surface point.

Comment: If the domain of $\sin \omega t$ be $[0,π]$ then it is possible to get approximate solutions.

Comment: @Andrei: no, rotation will also result in an harmonic term.

Comment: I see how $\sin\omega t+at^2+bt$ models the vertical position of one end of a spinning rod of length $2$ (spinning about its midpoint), but what if the other end touches down first?

Comment: @BarryCipra For a convex polyhedron each vertex will follow this equation except the $sin(\omega t)$ term would change phase/amplitude, but the overall equation will still have the same form, with different a/b and the offset in t. The touchdown moment is the minimum of solutions for individual vertexes.

Comment: @JenniferM., ah, nice. But doesn't all this assume the axis of rotation is parallel to the ground (and precession plays no role)?

Comment: @BarryCipra This assumes that the rotation is around one of the principal axes. This is the only case when rotation leads to harmonic oscillation of individual points. In case of general rotation both precession and nutation will play role, and this would lead to non-harmonic, and generally non-periodic oscillations.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is a transcendental equation. It can not be exactly solved but you can find the roots using numerical methods like Newton's method. However if you are still interested in having a closed form solution, you may use Bhaskara's approximation for domain $[-\frac {π}{2},\frac {π}{2}]$. For example, consider another related equation,
$$\cos \omega t + t^2 + bt - N = 0$$
From Bhaskara's approximation formula,
$$\cos \omega t ≈ \frac {π^2 - 4\omega^2 t^2}{π^2 + \omega^2 t^2}$$
The equation is reduced to a general quartic,
$$t^4+bt^3+(T^2 - (4+N))t^2+T^2bt+T^2(1-N)=0$$
Where $T=\frac {π}{\omega}$This can be solved using Ferrari's method (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ferrari%27s_Method). Although the computational cost is high and the solution may turn really ugly, yet it will give you much required insight into the dependence of the time of flight of the object on various parameters.

Comment: I totally agree with your approach but $$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad (-\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2)$$

Comment: Now I have corrected it. Well , thanks for pointing my error.

Comment: You are welcome ! Interesting problem from a numerical point of veiw. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as Awe Kumar Jha, considering $$\sin (\omega t) + at^2+bt=N$$ let
$$x=\omega t\qquad \alpha=\frac a{\omega^2}\qquad\beta=\frac b{\omega}$$ to make the equation
$$\sin(x)+\alpha x^2+\beta x=N$$ and use  Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$
$$4 \alpha  x^4+ 4( \beta - \pi  \alpha )x^3+ \left(5 \pi ^2 \alpha -4 \pi  \beta -4 N-16\right)x^2+\pi   (5 \pi  \beta +4
   N+16)x-5 \pi ^2 N=0\tag 1$$ which, as said,can be solved using Ferrari's method (this would be quite tedious).

You can use another approximation  (from far, not as good asBhaskara I's one ) minimizing with respect to $k$
$$\int_0^\pi \left[\sin(x)-k (\pi-x)x\right]^2\,dx=\frac{\pi ^5 }{30}k^2-8 k+\frac{\pi }{2}$$ to get $\color{blue}{k=\frac{120}{\pi ^5}}$ and then $\sin(x)\simeq k(\pi-x)x$. This leads to 
$$ (\alpha -k)x^2+ (\beta +\pi  k)x-N=0\tag 2$$ which is simpler for sure. Using its solution as $x_0$ you can start Newton iterations to polish the root accorging to
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\sin (x_n)+\alpha  x_n^2+\beta  x_n-N}{ \cos (x_n)+2 \alpha  x_n+\beta}$$

Let us try with $\alpha=0.4$, $\beta=0.6$, $N=2.345$. Solving $(1)$ gives $x^{(1)}_0 =1.26126$ while solving $(2)$ gives $x^{(2)}_0=1.27312$. Now, the iterates of Newton method starting with $x_0=x^{(2)}_0$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.273117520 \\
 1 & 1.260970996 \\
 2 & 1.260976964
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

**Edit**

To stay with a quadratic equation, we could be even more empirical (not respecting the values at end points) and write
$$\sin(x) \simeq a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$$ The same minimization method would lead to
$$a_0=\frac{12 \left(\pi ^2-10\right)}{\pi ^3}\qquad a_1=-\frac{60 \left(\pi ^2-12\right)}{\pi ^4}\qquad a_2=\frac{60 \left(\pi ^2-12\right)}{\pi ^5}$$ which would lead to $x^{(3)}_0=1.26757$.